# Encrypt a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `TblUserLogin` with columns `LoginID int`, `Password varchar(50)`, `LoginUserName varchar(150)`, `Designation varchar(100)`.

My requirement is that whenever we are using `select` statement to this table we are able to see the password which is entered (which is sensitive information).

Is there any way so that we can encrypt the password column so that when ever we use `select` statement that information will be seen in an encrypted way and will not affect the code which is accessing the password column or inserting new password?

In simple words when "The password column shown as encrypted when it is accessed from Management Studio using `select` statement, but when accessed programatically it returns the actual non-encrypted password".

Comment: 1) You can use a view and grand right permisions. 2) Hash the password is best to encript it.

Comment: You cannot have both - you either get the password back encrypted all the time, or you get it back in plain text (decrypted) all the time - you cannot have it be returned once encrypted, once clear-text. The easiest might be to just encrypt it in your app using a good cipher, and then store it into SQL Server. Then SQL Server will always show the encrypted version, while your app can check passwords entered by users against the encrypted version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[EncryptPasswd]
@user_id int,
@username varchar(255),
@passwd varchar(255)
As
Begin
Declare @res varbinary(2000)

IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name='##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
BY PASSWORD = 'xyz@123'


IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.certificates where name='EncryptTestCert')
CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
WITH SUBJECT = 'xyz@123'

IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name='TestTableKey') 
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert


INSERT INTO Users(user_id,username,passwd) 
SELECT @user_id,@username,ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),@passwd)
END
```

Use this sproc whenver you insert a new user into your user table.So this will encrypt the password and insert.

Answer (score 1):

In general, unless you absolutely can't avoid it, you should not store passwords in a database either in the clear or using reversible encryption.

Instead you should store a hash of the password, then when you need to compare it, hash the user input and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

you could encrypt the password in sql server 2008

read [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/) article, describes very clearly

Comment: Yeah, but you either get the password back encrypted (as gibberish) all the time, or you get it back in plain text (decrypted) all the time - you cannot have it be returned once encrypted, once clear-text